# How to change the default system console to Windows Terminal?

Tags: command-line

Any way to change the default system console to **Windows Terminal**?

[image]

Comment: For what purpose? You can open a console window and launch Blender with "\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\blender.exe" but if you accidentally close the console, Blender closes, too.

Comment: @RonJensen Just want a console with more customization. This is a solution. Thanks. If possible to run **Windows Terminal** after blender launching? That'd be better.